# Value set client side via javascript, not value when hitting server (master page, content page)

Tags: javascript, master-pages

I have a master page.  On one of the content pages I am setting a control value via javascript:

```
var bar = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField_ImgSVG.ClientID%>');
bar.Value = "1234";
```

However, when I try and retrieve this value on the server the value is always empty (c#):

```
string str_SVGImgVal = HiddenField_ImgSVG.Value;
```

I have set other hidden field values multiple times from the server and those values always remain valid, but not anything set client side;  Help?!

Thanks.

Comment: have you verified `bar` is not null?

Comment: Yes, it sets the value fine.

Comment: on the server side is the value being sent to the master page?

Comment: In JavaScript, the property name is `value`, not `Value`. Case matters :).

Comment: Mike, you are correct I realized it shortly after posting and was literally too embarrassed to come back and correct it!  It seems to have happened a few times recently where as soon as I post I realize the error...

Comment: nothing to be embarrassed about, I've done that on any number of occasions.  In fact I've just done it again by, likewise, not seeing it.  Sometimes a fresh pair of eye is the best debugger...cheers!  Or we can blame VS citing the need for improved intellisense